# How do I restore a tar Android backup directly to my phone?

Tags: adb, rooting, backup, internal-storage, shell

Android 11. I made a backup of my Internal Storage using this:

```
adb exec-out 'tar --create --exclude=data/media/0/TWRP \
data/media/0 2>/backup-errors.txt | \
gzip' | \
dd of=sdcardbackup-$(date +%Y%m%d).tar.gz && \
adb shell cat /backup-errors.txt
```

But how do I restore that directly to my internal storage after formatting?

Comment: https://twrp.me/faq/openrecoveryscript.html

Comment: guess something with exec-in - are you running adb from windows or linux host (there might be issue with carriage return \r on windows)?

Comment: @alecxs windows...

Comment: on windows exec-out always corrupt files this way, the only reason why it works gzip files missing newlines

Comment: what do i do???

Comment: suggested several alternatives. however on linux this will work: *'adb exec-in "gzip -d | tar -px" < C:\adb\sdcard\*.tar.gz'*

Comment: no way of doing it on windows with .sh ?

Comment: what is windows with .sh? from your question can see you are running `dd` and `date` from host, therefore i don't think your host is plain windows cmd.exe? is this wsl bash? have you tested?

Comment: running it as .sh file

Comment: .sh files are linux shell files they can't run on windows by default. furthermore a script is just a substitute for batch processing cmd lines, that still requires all the linux core utils used within script. if the above cmd did not work, how can it work from within shell script?